# Changing Underline color

Tags: html, css, underline

I have this code here:

```
echo "<u><font color='red'><br>$username</font></u>";
```

Firstly, as you can see, it's underlined (< u >). Second, all text is all red. Well is there anyway to leave the text ($username) red but the underline black?

Comment: And so the `<font>` tag.

Comment: `<u>` is deprecated in HTML4

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. The best you can do is to use a `border-bottom` with a different color, but that isn't *really* underlining.

Comment: Actually this appears to work... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804419/css-text-decoration-underline-color#12804560

Comment: This is wrong; see the comment about text-decoration-color below.

Comment: css 3 supports this. See browsers.
http://caniuse.com/#feat=text-decoration

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer anymore. See the `text-decoration: underline red;` answer below.

Answer (score 64):

There's now a new css3 property for this: [text-decoration-color](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-decor-3/#text-decoration-color-property)

So you can now have text in one color and a text-decoration underline - in a different color... without needing an extra 'wrap' element

```css
p {
  text-decoration: underline;
  -webkit-text-decoration-color: red; /* safari still uses vendor prefix */
  text-decoration-color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>black text with red underline in one element - no wrapper elements here!</p>
```

### [Codepen](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/YZaJrE?editors=1100)

**NB:**

1) [Browser Support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=text-decoration) is limited at the moment to Firefox and Chrome (fully supported as of V57) and Safari

2) You could also use the [text-decoration](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-decor-3/#text-decoration) shorthand property which looks like this:

```
<text-decoration-line> || <text-decoration-style> || <text-decoration-color>
```

...so using the `text-decoration` shorthand - the example above would simply be:

```
p {
  text-decoration: underline red;
}
```

```css
p {
  text-decoration: underline red;
}
```

```html
<p>black text with red underline in one element - no wrapper elements here!</p>
```

Comment: This is cool, but besides the lacking support - it's also nice to have a bit more control - which you can get with border-bottom, however - using inline-block on long stretches will surely break the magic... so this would be the best solution for that.

Comment: it's 2016 and still lacking support in Chrome. sigh.

Comment: Two years later, and this property still has virtually no browser support. Please, see [my method outlined below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557707/changing-underline-color/28917336#28917336) for single-line underlines.

Comment: @JasonS - Chrome now fully supports this :)

Answer (score 23):

Update from author:

**This answer is outdated since [text-decoration-color](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-decoration-color.asp) is now supported by most modern browsers.**

---

### :pseudo + em

In order to accurately replicate the size, stroke width, and positioning of the native [`text-decoration:underline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration) **without introducing extra HTML markup**, you should use a [`pseudo-element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) with [`em`](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html) units. This allows for accurate scaling of the element and native behavior without additional markup.

### CSS

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-table;
}

a:after {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 0.1em solid #f00;
  display: table-caption;
  caption-side: bottom;
  position: relative;
  margin-top:-0.15em;
}
```

By using display:[`table-caption`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/caption) and [`caption-side`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/caption-side) on the pseudo-element and display [`inline-table`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display), we can force the browser to vertically-align both line and link accurately, even when scaled.

In this instance, we use inline-table instead of inline-block to force the pseudo to display without the need to specify height or negative values.

### Examples

[**JSFIDDLE**: https://jsfiddle.net/pohuski/8yfpjuod/8/](https://jsfiddle.net/pohuski/8yfpjuod/8/)
[**CODEPEN**: http://codepen.io/pohuski/pen/vEzxPj | (example with scaling)](http://codepen.io/pohuski/pen/vEzxPj)

**Successfully Tested On:**
Internet Explorer: 8, 9, 10, 11
Firefox: 41, 40, 39, 38, 37, 36
Chrome: 45, 44, 43, 42
Safari: 8, 7, 6.2
Mobile Safari: 9.0, 8.0
Android Browser: 4.4, 2.3
Dolphin Mobile: 8, 11.4

Comment: +1 for use of peudo elements, which offers  a pure-css approach with great control over the properties of the 'underline'

Comment: Great solution but I can only get this to look good in Chrome, is it suppose to work in other browsers as well? It's completely broken in Firefox.

Comment: @RichardB I have updated the answer to use the `caption-side` property, which should account for those browser quirks. I updated the fiddle and codepen links.

Comment: Behavior for multi line text/link is not same as with text-decoration. Still it's better to use one more element/span.

Comment: This doesn't work with elements that wrap on to multiple lines, or if you have a 1 line element that scales down and wraps for mobile devices. If you add enough content to your tests they will break.

Comment: In addition to what has been said, this renders underlines incorrectly with descender letters, e.g. `g`.

Answer (score 12):

In practice, it is possible, if you use `span` element instead of `font`:

```
<style>
u { color: black; }
.red { color: red }
</style>
<u><span class='red'><br>$username</span></u>
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yucca42/VHRzU/). Appears to work on Chrome, Safari, Firefox, IE, Opera (tested on Win 7 with newest versions).

The code in the question should work, too, but it does not work for some reason on WebKit browsers (Chrome, Safari).

By the [CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#propdef-text-decoration): “The color(s) required for the text decoration must be derived from the 'color' property value of the element on which 'text-decoration' is set. The color of decorations must remain the same even if descendant elements have different 'color' values.”

Comment: Note for present-day readers: `<u>` is deprecated, but you can achieve the same style with other elements (e.g. div or span) and CSS as well.

Comment: `<u>` was deprecated in HTML 4, but HTML 5 gave it the status of a normal element (and HTML 5 doesn’t use the term “deprecated”; instead, it uses “obsolete”). HTML 5 redefines the meaning of `<u>` in a weird way, but that’s a different story. Regarding this question, the only thing that matters in `<u>` is that it (by default) causes its content to appear as underlined.
https://www.w3.org/TR/html/textlevel-semantics.html#elementdef-u

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way I've tackled this is with CSS:

```
<style>
.redUnderline {
    color: #ff0000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}
</style>
<span class="redUnderline">$username</span>
```

Also, for an actual underline, if your item is a link, this works:

```
<style>
a.blackUnderline {
   color: #000000;
   text-decoration: underline;
}
.red {
    color: #ff0000;
}
</style>
<a href="" class="blackUnderline"><span class="red">$username</span></a>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the box-shadow property to simulate an underline.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eMWSQ/1/).
The idea is to use two layered box shadows to position the line in the same place as an underline.

```
a.underline {
    text-decoration: none;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -4px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), inset 0 -5px 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way that the one described by danield is to have a child container width display inline, and the tipography color you want.  The parent element width the text-decoration, and the color of underline you want. Like this:

```css
div{text-decoration:underline;color:#ff0000;display:inline-block;width:50px}
div span{color:#000;display:inline}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Hover me, i can have many lines</span>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 This is the modern version of what [Jukka](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12558784/216129) described in his answer (as `<u>` is deprecated).

Answer (score 2):

A pseudo element works best.

```
a, a:hover {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  top:90%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-bottom: solid 1px red;
}
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6YJHM/).

You don't need any extra elements, you can position it as close or far as you want from the text (border-bottom is kinda far for my liking), there aren't any extra colors that show up if your link is over a different colored background (like with the box-shadow trick), and it works in all browsers (text-decoration-color only supports Firefox as of yet).

Possible downside: The link can't be position:static, but that's probably not a problem the vast majority of the time. Just set it to relative and all is good.

Answer (score 2):

Best way I came across doing is like this:

HTML5:

```html
<p>Initial Colors <a id="new-color">Different Colors</a></p>
```

CSS3:

```css
p {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration-line: underline;
    text-decoration-color: #a11015;
}

p #new-color{
    color: #a11015;
    text-decoration-line: underline;
    text-decoration-color: #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this CSS to "simulate" an underline:

```
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your `<span>` with a `<a>` and use this little JQuery plugin to color the underline.
You can modify the color by passing a parameter to the plugin.

```
    (function ($) {
        $.fn.useful = function (params) {

            var aCSS = {
                'color' : '#d43',
                'text-decoration' : 'underline'
            };

            $.extend(aCSS, params);

            this.wrap('<a></a>');
            var element = this.closest('a');
            element.css(aCSS);
            return element;
        };
    })(jQuery);
```

Then you call by writing this :

```
    $("span.name").useful({color:'red'});
```

```js
$(function () {

        var spanCSS = {
            'color' : '#000',
            'text-decoration': 'none'
        };
        
        $.fn.useful = function (params) {
            
            var aCSS = {
                'color' : '#d43',
                'text-decoration' : 'underline'
            };

            $.extend(aCSS, params);
            this.wrap('<a></a>');
            this.closest('a').css(aCSS);
        };

        // Use example:
        $("span.name").css(spanCSS).useful({color:'red'});



    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="container">

    <div class="user important">
        <span class="name">Bob</span>
        -
        <span class="location">Bali</span>
    </div>

    <div class="user">
        <span class="name">Dude</span>
        -
        <span class="location">Los Angeles</span>
    </div>


    <div class="user">
        <span class="name">Gérard</span>
        -
        <span class="location">Paris</span>
    </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

here we can create underline with color in text

```html
<u style="text-decoration-color: red;">The color of the lines should now be red!</u>
```

or

The color of the lines should now be red!

```html
<h1 style=" text-decoration:underline; text-decoration-color: red;">The color of the lines should now be red!</u>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to do this is in your css, use:

```
text-decoration-color: red;
```

This will change the color of the underline without changing the color of your text. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Problem with `border-bottom` is the extra distance between the text and the line. Problem with `text-decoration-color` is lack of browser support. Therefore my solution is the use of a background-image with a line. This supports any markup, color(s) and style of the line. `top` (12px in my example) is dependent on `line-height` of your text.

```
 u {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: transparent url(blackline.png) repeat-x 0px 12px;
}
```