# How to underline only the text, in a different color, in a single block element?

Tags: html, css

I want to produce the following result with a single element:

```
<style type="text/css">
    div { background-color: #000; color: #fff; }
    span { border-bottom: 1px solid #f00; }
</style>
<div><span>White text, red underline, black background</span></div>
```

jFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ARbmG/

Is this possible?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ARbmG/

Comment: You just did it, why ask how to do it ?

Comment: If you want *only* the text underlined, then what you have is pretty much the easiest way to do it with the least amount of markup.

Comment: My example uses two elements, I want to know if it is possible to do it with only one

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Comment: Yes CSS3 is acceptable--well, that is, if it can be done with CSS3 then I would like to see how!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

related to : [CSS text-decoration underline color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804419/css-text-decoration-underline-color)  and  [Changing Underline color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557707/changing-underline-color)

**NO, you cannot 'yet'** change text-decoration underline color in a cross-plateform, cross-browser way.

- [Non-working solution](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/CSS/text-decoration-color)  or  [jsFiddle-working solution](http://jsfiddle.net/ARbmG/3/)
- [W3C infos](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-css3-text-20101005/#text-decoration-color)  or  [/css-text-decor-3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-decor-3/#text-decoration-color)
- [MSDN infos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg721748%28v=expression.40%29.aspx)

Mozilla soluce :

```
span {
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration: underline;
    -moz-text-decoration-color: red;
    /* you'll have to search for other -proprietary selectors */
}
```

Otherwise, to border-bottom an inline element : You just did it.

Comment: Thanks Milche that is probably as close as I can get.  I didn't know about text-decoration-color.  My next question would be how to adjust the height of the underline, but it doesn't look like CSS3 will do that.

Comment: Height of the underline ? Wo! Calm down !

Comment: I will probably end up using jQuery to insert the inner element for the underlines, I was just hoping to do it (somehow) with CSS only.

Answer (score 2):

I tried a couple of things and I came up with this odd little thingy. I may not recommend this, but it's very close to what you want using only one single HTML tag:

**HTML**

```
<span>White text, red underline, black background</span>
```

**CSS**

```
span {
    color: white;
    background: black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}

span:after {
    content: '_';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
    color: black;
}
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/uWGx5/

Comment: what happens if there is other elements to influence the position absolute? :)

Comment: +1, its not the actual answer, but can help on future reference. :)

Comment: That is very clever...  Definitely worth hanging on to for future reference.  Thank you!

Comment: @Ark I didn't answer you question yesterday. Sorry. This will work as long as the `<span>` has `static` positioning. In this case the block will always fill the width of its parent element. It will also work if an `inline-block`-element will come right before the `<span>`. In this case it will take the width that is left in this line.

Answer (score 0):

I found an even better solution.

My example--white text, red underline, black background--wasn't 100% accurate.  It has to be a "block" element, but the background can be transparent.

Here is a new one: 
http://jsfiddle.net/gpNZX/2/

The magic is the :before and :after '\A', which is an escaped ASCII line feed.  I also tried using  { content:' '; display:block; } but it didn't seem to work 100% in all browsers.

```
span {
    ...
    display: inline;
    ...
}
span:before {
    content: '\A';
    white-space: pre;
}
span:after {
    content: '\A';
    white-space: pre;
}
```