# How to add 2 border colors using pseudo elements or without using extra markup?

Tags: html, css

I give up on this...

```css
.wrapper {
     border: 1px solid #aaa;
     width: 300px;
     height: 300px;
     padding: 20px
}
h2 {
     border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
     display: block;
}
h2 span {
     border-bottom: 2px solid #f00;
     display: inline-block;
     margin-bottom: -2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h2><span>TITLE HERE</span></h2>
</div>
```

Please run the code snippet to see my objective.
The length of the RED border is the length of the text title. 
How can I achieve that without having to add the span or any markup? I tried adding the gray border to pseudo-element ::before but it only doubles up the length of the red border, the gray border should fill the rest of the box. Please help me play with it. thanks!

Comment: This has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15230888/how-to-underline-only-the-text-in-a-different-color-in-a-single-block-element

Comment: Just a bit of similarity... :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using two pseudo-elements.

Both of the pseudo-elements are absolutely positioned *relative* to the top of the parent element. For the red border, the key is setting the parent element to `inline-block` so that it has a "shrink to fit" based width. Unfortunately, this method requires a hardcoded width for the second pseudo-element equal to the width of the `.wrapper` element.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/kuorhd9a/)

```css
.wrapper {
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    padding:20px
}
h2 {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
h2:before,
h2:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; right: 0;
    top: 100%;
}
h2:after {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #f00;
}
h2:before {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <h2>TITLE HERE</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to adjust the wrapper if the gray border will follow its length.

Comment: This is probably the best solution so far. I will just have to adjust the width of h2:before. Thanks dude.

Comment: @wjR. Good idea, that's a great answer. +1. It's better than mine, I didn't think of adding the red border to the `h2` element itself.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to push it some more and came up with this solution. I use index-1 and 2 for layer order. The solution of Josh is good but it doesn't support text-align property. I need text-align:right in particular. Without using z-index seems to be fine when running it here but when I apply it into my design, it won't work without it.

```css
.wrapper {
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    padding:20px
}
h2 {
    display:inline;
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    z-index:1
}
h2:after {
    content: '';
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
    margin-top:-1px;
    z-index:2
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<h2>TITLE HERE</h2>
</div>
```