# why is text-decoration considered part of the foreground

Tags: html, css

```
<span>Teaching kids to reach their creative and intellectual potentials through Computer Science.</span>
```

Above is my HTML and below is my CSS:

```
span { text-decoration: underline; color: red }
```

If `text-decoration` is considered part of the foreground, than how can the `text-decoration-color` property change the `text-decoration` color without changing the `color` of the font?

Comment: Very rude, I actually just read the documentation (foreign words and non-explicit annotations).

Comment: Which documentation? I recommend reading HTMLDog - http://www.htmldog.com/references/ - it's mainly for HTML 4 Strict, but can be used for HTML5 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use -webkit-text-decoration-color to change it on Chrome. However, note that Experimental Web Platform Features has to be enabled for it to work. So for now, Chrome just simply does not support this css property.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `text-decoration-color` cross browsers.
See [text-decoration-color support browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=text-decoration-color). If you really needed to change the underline color maybe this link can help you. [CSS text-decoration underline color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804419/css-text-decoration-underline-color)

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved, however, it requires your text to be wrapped in a `<span>` tag.

Instead of using the `<u>` tag use [**`text-decoration`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration) with `underline` as a value.

**Code Snippet:**

```css
p {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
span {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<p><span>Teaching kids to reach their creative and intellectual potentials through Computer Science.</span>
</p>
```