# How to change width of underline in css

Tags: html, css

I have a cell in a table like this:

```
<td><b>Grand Total</b></td>
```

I need to give it a line under the text "Grand Total". I used `text-decoration: underline;`. It worked well, but I need to change the color and thickness of the underline. I used `text-decoration-color: red;` to add color but it doesn't work. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You can use border-bottom property to set width and color of the underline

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use `border-bottom`  define color cording  like this

```css
b {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    padding: 0 0 4px;
}
```

```html
<td><b>Grand Total</b></td>
```

Answer (score 8):

The best approach is to use the `text-decoration-thickness` css property. Here is the [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-thickness) to the documentation. A simple code sample would look something like:

```
text-decoration: underline solid black 2px;
```

The `2px` here is the `text-decoration-thickness` or rather the width of the underline.

Comment: supported in all but FF on Android and IE https://caniuse.com/?search=text-decoration-thickness

Comment: @Fanky Now supported on Firefox Android too for about a month, so it's safe to say going forward this is the future-proof answer that should make the others obsolete. I had no idea this property was a thing and it's nice not to have use the old hacks for it.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot modify the width of `underline` tag. Instead go for `Border-bottom` approach and change it's properties as required.

```css
.underline {
  border-bottom: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><b class="underline">Grand Total</b></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use pseudo elements like `:before` and `:after` to control the length of the underline as well

```css
td {
  position: relative;
}

td:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  bottom: -5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Grand Total</b></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It doesn't underline the entire text

Comment: The requirement was to control the width of the undeline. Just give the width to 100% it'll underline the entire text.

Comment: Oh, I thought OP meant thickness. You may be right.

Answer (score 3):

Usually I use these three CSS properties to style the underline

### To set the thickness of the underline

text-decoration-thickness: 3px;

### To set the color of the underline

text-decoration-color: red;

### To offset the underline

text-underline-offset: 5px;

Answer (score 2):

You should give class or id to your specific line, like:

HTML:

```
<td><b id="total">Grand Total</b></td>
```

CSS:

```
#total {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  padding: 0 0 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804419/css-text-decoration-underline-color#12804560)

```css
td {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

span {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><b><span>Grand Total</span></b></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How can I specify the width for underline?Thank you for the answer

Comment: @Jibin Not really sure how

Comment: Thank you for your support @ Carl Jan

Answer (score 2):

If you target your 'b', you can use a background gradient which will allow you to adjust the thickness of the line and the line's vertical placement.

eg.

```
b {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fdb514 50%, transparent 50%);
    background-position: 0px 0.9em;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: 1px 15px;
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Very nice solution. Thank you @Reece.

Answer (score 0):

```
td {
position: relative;
}

td::after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
width: 30%;
display: block;
height: 5px;
background-color: red;
bottom: -5px;
}
```

To control the width, you just change the width from 100% to whatever value you wish.