# How to set underline color in Word Plug-In

Tags: javascript, cpu-word

I used js to develop a word Plug-In. I'm using the following code

```
font.underline = Word.UnderlineType.thick
```

I found this code can only set the type. How do i set the underline color?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS text-decoration underline color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804419/css-text-decoration-underline-color)

Comment: thank you   This looks like a browser but I'm trying to manipulate a word document