# how to change the colour property of <u> tag used for a text

Tags: html, css, laravel-4

i am using the following code to display a string in multiple lines and each line is underlined,but i want to change the colour of the underline tag and i want to use the text-align:justify property to display the text justified,but its not working properly.

```
<div>
        <u><b>Uitgevoerde werkzaamheden</b></u>
        <u><p class="test">{{{$werkbon_report->work_preformed}}}</p></u>
</div>
```

i want there is a underline below the text and its color is blue and its width is 100% regardless of the width of the text.

how to modify the default color of the  tag used to underline the text.

my css class

```
 p.test{
    width:100%; 
    word-wrap:break-word;
    text-align: justify;
    line-height:200%;
}
```

Comment: use `span` for it...`u` wont help you achieve your purpose!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing Underline color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557707/changing-underline-color)

Comment: This is about changing the color of underline, and it has been asked and answered several times at SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont think you can change it that way....use `span` instead

```
html, body {
    width:100%; /* make sure this is present in your css, else 100% wont work */
}
p.test {
    width:100%; /* this is dependent on parents width */
    word-wrap:break-word;
    text-align: justify;
    line-height:200%;

}
p.test > span {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    padding-bottom:3px; /* how low underline should be */
    border-bottom:1px solid blue; /*underline color*/
    color:red; /*text color*/
    text-align:justify;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<p class="test"><span><b>Uitgevoerde werkzaamheden</b></span>

</p>
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/VpyVD/2/) (*only text width line*)

[**second demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/VpyVD/3/)  (*browser width line*)

Comment: i want to change only the underline colour not the text colour.

Comment: please check the 2nd demo...ur text color is intact!!

Comment: can you please heck my 2nd line in the code which is a string and should be displayed as multiline string and all line should be underline as you have done for the first line

Comment: if you give the `html output` for 2nd line,i might be able to help....in present way, i don't know the output!! :)

Comment: the 2nd line is nothing but a string value coming dynamically from the database,but i want to display it as multiple lines for which i have used the wordwrap property as you can see in my code,but the lines should also be displayed as like as the first line i.e it must be underlined and the underline colour must be blue and its width is 100%.it is lookwise just as you have done for the 1st line.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44388/discussion-between-noobeditor-and-himanshusamantaray)

Comment: yes the output should be displayed like this,but in my case the string is coming from the database,which is a large string,i am using the wordwrap property to break it into different lines and be displayed as you have shown but with a little modification,the last line's underline width must be also 100%.

Comment: This does not set underline at all but a bottom border. This, and a real underline color change, *can* be done whether `u` is used or not.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela : i am eager to know how it can be done your way!! :)

Comment: This question is a duplicate. Any efforts on improving answers should be focused on earlier questions, after reading their answers.

Answer (score 1):

Using `word-break` won't break your text into two lines, for that either you need to use `<br />` tag, or you need to assign some short `width` to your `p` tag, secondly if you expect that it should justify than, it won't as there's only single word on a single line so don't expect CSS to space up the characters for you on a single line...

If you want to space up your characters, than you will have to use `letter-spacing` property

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/A5thU/)

Here, in the above demo, I've assigned some fixed `width` to your `p` element, and than I just used a space for first word, just to show you that `text-align: justify` works well...

And, lastly, if you want to have a different underline color, you cannot customize that by simply using `u` tag, you need to use `span` around the words, with `border-bottom` property

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/A5thU/1/)

[image]

Comment: @NoobEditor Well he selecte yours so voted you too :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, Add `div u`

```
p.test{
   width:100%; 
   word-wrap:break-word;
   text-align: justify;
   line-height:200%;
   text-decoration: none; 
   border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}

div u{
   text-decoration: none; 
   border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/WQabG/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to put a span in you paragraph, you can try it like this:

HTML

```
<p class="test"><span>Uitgevoerde werkzaamheden</span></p>
```

CSS

```
p.test{
width:100%; 
word-wrap:break-word;
text-align: justify;
line-height:200%;
font-weight: bold;
}

p.test > span {
border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/33YHg/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
p.test, p.test u {
color:green;
text-align:justify
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this help you??

```
 <head>
<style>
p.test{
    line-height:200%;
}
hr { 
border-color: blue;
margin-top: -20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p class="test"><b>Uitgevoerde werkzaamheden</b></p>
<hr>
</body>
```