# CSS: Text to sit on baseline of chosen colour

Tags: html, css, text, typography

In the past I have struggled to achieve the effect of having text sit on a baseline of a specified colour. Today I had a bit of a luck and made some progress.

However, although my results give me the effect I was aiming for something is telling me there is an easier way to achieve the same effect.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

This JSFiddle demonstrates my desired effect and my current method of achieving it.

http://jsfiddle.net/leeboyce/QZ5F5/1/

```
<h2>
    <span>
         Is there another way to <br /> achieve this effect? <br /><br />Aim:<br /> have different coloured underline sitting on the text baseline
    </span>
</h2>

h2 {
    font-size: 2.4em;
    line-height: 1em;
    color: #f78f1e;
    font-weight: bold;
}
h2 span {
    background-color: transparent;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#d2d2d2), color-stop(0%, transparent)) 0 1em;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #d2d2d2 0%, transparent 1px) 0 1em;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #d2d2d2 0%, transparent 1px) 0 1em;
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #d2d2d2 0%, transparent 1px) 0 1em;
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #d2d2d2 0%, transparent 1px) 0 1em;
    background: linear-gradient(bottom, #d2d2d2 0%, transparent 1px) 0 1em;
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 2.4em;
    -moz-background-size: 100% 2.4em;
    -ms-background-size: 100% 2.4em;
    -o-background-size: 100% 2.4em;
    background-size: 100% 2.4em;
}
```

[image: screenshot of what i currently see in firefox & chrome]

Comment: Maybe this will help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557707/changing-underline-color

Comment: Not seeing any underline in that fiddle in Chrome. Am I missing somthing?

Comment: I can see the underline in Mozilla, but nothing else that the CSS hints at. What are we supposed to see?

Comment: Anyway, although I still don't know what you're after, I'm pretty sure that the `2.4em` in the css for the span is not right. Unless you mean 5.76 times the size of the surrounding text.

Comment: Sorry - I was struggling to word it well so i have attached a screenshot of what i'm currently seeing in Firefox and Chrome.

The important thing is - i want to be able to control how close to the text the underline sits in relation to the texts baseline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way, adding an additional span: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QZ5F5/4/)

```
<h2>
    <span class="ul">
        <span class="text">Is there another way to <br />
achieve this effect? <br /><br />Aim:<br /> have different coloured 
underline sitting on the text baseline
        </span>
    </span>
</h2>
```

and the CSS

```
h2 {
    font-size: 2.4em;
    line-height: .8em;
    color: #f78f1e;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.ul {
    border-bottom:1px solid #cccccc;
}
.text{
    vertical-align:-6px;
}
```

HTH,
-Ted

Edited to add: Here's a second fiddle just using the text-decoration:underline css, if that underline works for you [another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QZ5F5/7/)

Comment: Thanks @Ted, this looks like it does exactly what i'm looking for. Annoyingly simple haha.

Comment: Cool... if that's what you're looking for, mark the question answered :)