# Set border of the text rather than the input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, html-input

I have an `input` field, I want to make a hover effect on **its text**: make the bottom border of **its text** colourful when the mouse is on it.

The following code makes the bottom border of the entire input field colourful.

The following code works fine for `value2`, which is not an `input`.

Does anyone know how to work on the text inside the input, rather than the input field?

[JSBin](https://jsbin.com/tewawoniji/3/edit?html,output)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    input {
      font-size: 20px;
      border:none;
      display: inline-block;
      background-color:transparent;
    }
    .item {
        font-size: 20px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    input:hover, .item:hover {
      border-bottom: 2px solid #42b983;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="value1">
  <br/>
  <div class="item">{{value2}}</div>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
      $scope.value1 = "value1";
      $scope.value2 = "value2"
    }])
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `border-bottom` you could use:

```
 input:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  -webkit-text-decoration-color: red;
  -moz-text-decoration-color: red;
  text-decoration-color: red;
}
```

Note that browser support is limited.
See:
http://caniuse.com/#search=text-decoration-color

Comment: Why the colour is always `black`? [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/kuvinaneto/1/edit?html,output)

Comment: It's red for me on Chrome & Firefox when looking at your fiddle with my additions.

Comment: It requires a [browser support](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21599113/702977)

Comment: Yes I just saw support was just added for chrome in the latest version.
http://caniuse.com/#search=text-decoration-color

Comment: The page will be public and I will not be able to change the setting of visitors, so this `text-decoration-color` solution does not suit my case...

Comment: I think you will have to resort to JS then.

A way around it would be to create another text field positioned exactly at the same place, that would mirror the typed text. This field will have a different color to the text - but it will be hidden "below" the current field, so only the underline would be visible by the user.

Answer (score 0):

```
input:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    -moz-text-decoration-color: #42b983; /* Code for Firefox */
    text-decoration-color: #42b983;
}
```