# Use of "text-decoration-color" is not working

Tags: css

I want to color the text decoration. I got a tutorial from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-decoration-color.asp)

And tried this

```
text-decoration: underline;
text-decoration-color: #dddddd;
```

But it is not working. Is this not valid? Is there any other way to color the underline?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557707/changing-underline-color

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing Underline color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557707/changing-underline-color)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`text-decoration-color` has [minimal browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-color#Browser_compatibility)

Instead, you can use something like a span to re-colour your text:

```css
p {
  color: red;  /* colour of underline */
  text-decoration: underline;
}

span {
  color: black; /* original colour of p */
}
```

```html
<p><span>underline is red, text is black</span></p>
```

Comment: In addiction for a more detailed view of browser support see [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=text-decoration-color)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is likely to affect another class

```css
p {
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-color: red!important;
}
```

```html
<p>test</p>
```

Comment: It is not working. I am using Chrome. Can you please try and see ?

Answer (score 1):

Update: it works on Safari & Safari iOS with the `-webkit-` prefix!

```css
p {
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-color: red;
    -webkit-text-decoration-color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>test</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following method to add under the line in your string.

1) You can use text-decoration to add underline in the bottom of the string like below.Please add your CSS try to this way.

Following demos are fine for working me.

```
<style type="text/css">
.underline 
{   
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-color: red;
    /*color: blue;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;*/
}
</style>

<span class="underline">hello world</span>
```

2) If try to file in the first step so, you can try to second way to set the border in bottom of the string

```
<style type="text/css">
.underline 
{   
    /*text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-color: red;*/
    color: blue;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
</style>

<span class="underline">hello world</span>
```