# Modifying `text-decoration-color` with jQuery in Safari

Tags: jquery, css

I have an element:

```js
$('.myElement').click(function () {
  $('.myElement').css('text-decoration-color', 'red')
});
```

```css
.myElement {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
font-size: 16px;
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="myElement">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus fringilla ultrices hendrerit. Vestibulum eget volutpat ante. Proin quis elit molestie, lacinia purus a, vulputate purus.</textarea>
```

This snippet has an animation, so when you click it, the underline turns red. This works in Chrome, but not in Safari. Does anyone knows why, and how to make it work?

Thanks!

Comment: Safari only has Partial support with -webkit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing Underline color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557707/changing-underline-color)

Answer (score 0):

Try with prefix `-webkit`. It's not fully supported without prefix on all browsers. https://caniuse.com/#search=text-decoration-color

If you want to have underline with red color supported by all browesers, you should do this in other way than using `text-decoration-color`. As you can see it's not supported in `IE` and `Edge`. You can do this using `::after` pseudoelement and styling this with for example `border` colored `red`